# Typing a certain key causes TextMate to save the file

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Every time I type a <kbd>T</kbd> in Textmate, it tries to save the file. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I was messing with some bundles yesterday so it might be related to that.

Comment: Does it happen regardless of the currently selected language?

Comment: yeah, plain text, c, applescript - I'm 95% sure this is some bundle I tried to add in the past couple of days. I don't really use them that much so was some mistake I made.

Comment: Are you using the current released version of TextMate, or the alpha preview version of TextMate 2?

Comment: current released version

Answer (score 1):

You can search for bundle items with a certain key equivalent from the *Search Bundle Item…* menu item. Click the magnifying glass and select *Key equivalent*, then type `t` into the search field. It should show you which bundle item is triggered when pressing `t`.

Example bundle item and search result:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Beat me by one second. Do you have any idea where those key equivalents are stored internally? Couldn't find them in the bundles themselves, nor in `com.macromates.textmate.plist` (although the latter seems to modify when setting the keyboard shortcut, but a `diff` wouldn't show any change).

Comment: @slhck Where are you looking? Everything you do custom is in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles` as a "diff bundle" from the pristine one. Snippets and commands contain the key equivalents inline, at least those I checked.

Comment: Hm. I tried it again, this time it worked, shown as the `keyEquivalent`, as expected. Maybe TextMate didn't save the difference last time I tried.